# How to make changed module files take effect?

Tags: magento2, module, third-party-module, magento-2.2.5

I changed my `extra.phtml` file in a module that I already have installed, and that module is (i think) dependent on another module.

I've done all of these:

- disable/reenable module
- remove entry from setup_module table
- setup:upgrade
- setup:static-content:deploy
- cache:flush
- setup:db-schema:upgrade
- setup:db-data:upgrade
- indexer:reindex
- deleting all the cache folders

but my changes are still not there.

Here is the source tree of the two modules:

[image]

Notice how the Sample module is the only one that has the "Setup" folder with only "InstallData" script.

The `.phtml` file I changed is under `Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/extra.phtml`.

All the things I've googled tell me to delete the module rows in the `setup_module` table and then `setup:upgrade`. I tried that and my changes were still not there.

Here's my `catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
    <block class="Magepeople\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra"
        name="product.view.extra"
        template="Magepeople_Catalog::product/view/extra.phtml"
        after="product.info.addtocart">
    </block>
  </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

And my `extra.phtml` file:

```
<?php /* @var $block \Test\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Extra */?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<?php //print_r($_product->getsample_label); ?>
<?php  
$tag = 0;
if($_product->getSample_price_guest()){
 $tag = 1;   
} else{
  $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
  if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    if($_product->getSample_customer_group()){
        $grouparray = implode(',',$_product->getSample_customer_group());
        $gid = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); 
        if(in_array($gid,$grouparray)){
            $tag = 1; 
        }
    }
    // get Customer Group Id
  }
}?>
<?php if($tag):?>
        <button type="submit"  title="Add to Cart" class="action secondary full-width" id="product-sample-button">
            <span><?php echo $_product->getSample_label();?></span>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="" id="sampleorder" value="1" />  
        <script>
            require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

            $(document).ready(function(){
             // put your code here if you want it in document.ready 
                $("#product-sample-button")
                    .detach().
                    insertAfter("div.box-tocart");
                $('#product-sample-button').click(function(){
                    $('#sampleorder').attr('name','sampleorder');
                 });

            });

            //jQuery( document ).ready(function() {



         })
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your `catalog_product_view.xml` and `extra.phtml` files? And What do they do?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Updated. The `catalog_product_view.xml` defines where to place the `extra.phtml` and the `extra.phtml` defines what actually shows.